# Android pager indicator of where I am

Tags: android, fragment, pager

I'm using a pager on my application, and there is some texts view uppon it which lead toward a specific screen when I clic on it.

I want to paint the text of the current screen in a different color. when I click on them obviously no problems, but when i scroll, i have difficuties to do so.
I tried to use the adapter but it doesn't seem to work.

does somebody have an idea how to detect in wich screen I am ?

Answer (score 0):

found it, just needed to use `mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()...`